# I got one error"Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" when I using mysqli_multi_query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

I want to excute two update sql by using $mysqli->multi_query($sql);But I just get this error info below:

> PHP message: UPDATE table1 SET status=1;UPDATE table2 SET
>   name='b'|Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" while
>   reading response header from upstream,

When I run the query string manually in phpmyadmin, everything works fine as it should.

there is my code:

```
$mysqli = new MySQLi(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
$mysqli->query("set names utf8");
$sql = "UPDATE table1 SET status=1;UPDATE table2 SET name='b";

if ($mysqli->multi_query($sql))  
{  
  do {  

    $mysqli->use_result();

  } while ($mysqli->more_results() && $mysqli->next_result()); 

} else {
    error_log($sql."|".mysqli_error($mysqli));
    return false;
}
```

Is there any wrong with my code?

================================
I have resolve my question by using this code:

```
$mysqli = new MySQLi(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
$mysqli->query("set names utf8");
$sql = "UPDATE table1 SET status=1;UPDATE table2 SET name='b";

if ($mysqli->multi_query($sql))  
{  
  do {  

    $res = $mysqli->use_result();  
    mysqli_free_result($res);

  } while ($mysqli->more_results() && $mysqli->next_result()); 

} else {
    error_log($sql."|".mysqli_error($mysqli));
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Did you checked docs? Especially [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php#110155)? I think you should clear you result queue after each request to database.

Comment: Make sure you've cleared out the queue of results. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php#110155

Answer (score 1):

You **don't want**  to excute two update sql by using $mysqli->multi_query()

Execute them separately, using mysqli::query()

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new MySQLi(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

$mysqli->query("UPDATE table1 SET status=1");
$mysqli->query("UPDATE table2 SET name='b");
```

as simple as that

Note that if these queries are not static but accept variables, then you must use prepare()/execute() instead of query()

Comment: I think I have to use $mysqli->multi_query(),because I must ensure that two updates will excute correctly Simultaneously